Как сделть меню выбора в параметре команды discord.py?
import discord
from discord import app_commands
import datetime
from discord.ui import Button, View
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(
    name="close-create",
    description="Создать клоуз.",
    guild=discord.Object(id=1255608945922539540)
)
async def close(interaction, игра: ):
    print('2323')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1255608945922539540))
    print("Ready!")

client.run('')

Вот мой код. Как сделать в параметре игра: меню выбора игр? Чтобы юзер мог выбрать один из вариантов туда
ниже фото как должно быть

Воспользуйтесь options аргументом в декораторе Client.slash_command(), выглядеть это будет примерно следующим образом:
@tree.slash_command(
options=[
        create_option(
            name="reaction",
            description="Реакция, которую вы хотите использовать",
            option_type=SlashCommandOptionType.STRING,
            choices=[
                create_choice(name="Суицид", value="suicide"),
                create_choice(name="Плакать", value="cry"),
                create_choice(name="Радоваться", value="happy"),
                # Ну и дальше таким же темпом
            ]
        )
    ]
)


Писал без ide, поэтому если в коде есть синтаксические ошибки, доверьтесь автокомплиту

Спасибо большое, а из какой библиотеки нужно импортировать create_option?
